# Receiving a NullPointerException Error in a Java App in Android Studio, cannot see problem with id

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Receiving this error:

```
2022-08-04 21:01:08.374
9858-9858/com.erample.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
main
    Process: com.erample.myapplication, PID: 9858
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.erample.myapplication.ui.TermAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TermAdapter.java:61)
        at com.erample.myapplication.ui.TermAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TermAdapter.java:18)
```

---

```java
public class TermAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TermAdapter.TermViewHolder> {
    class TermViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView termItemView;
        private TermViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            termItemView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.term_detail_Term_Name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    final Terms current=mTerms.get(position);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context, CourseList.class);
                    intent.putExtra("termID", current.getTermID());
                    intent.putExtra("termName", current.getTermName());
                    intent.putExtra("termYear", current.getTermYear());
                    intent.putExtra("termStartDate", current.getTermStartDate());
                    intent.putExtra("termEndDate", current.getTermEndDate());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private List<Terms> mTerms;
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public TermAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TermAdapter.TermViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.term_list_item,parent, false);
        return new TermViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TermAdapter.TermViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(mTerms!=null){
            Terms current=mTerms.get(position);
            String name= current.getTermName();
            holder.termItemView.setText(name);
        }
        else {
            holder.termItemView.setText("No term name");
        }
    }
    public void setTerms(List<Terms> terms){
        mTerms=terms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mTerms!=null){
            return mTerms.size();
            }
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

The `findViewById(R.id.term_detail_Term_Name);` is pulling from here:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/termLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/term_detail_Term_Name"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/term_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/term_detail_Term_Year"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/term_year"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/term_detail_Term_Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Usually - there could be a disconnect between the Java and XML files - but both of those are named the same.

I'm not sure what I'm missing - and all of this is like a language from another whole planet for me.  Any help is appreciated. I've looked through a bunch of similar tickets - and checked the connections between the find by ID and the XML ID.

Additional Context:
Line 61 is holder.termItemView.setText(name); in this block: `@Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TermAdapter.TermViewHolder holder, int position) { if(mTerms!=null){ Terms current=mTerms.get(position); String name= current.getTermName(); holder.termItemView.setText(name);`

Comment: Which line is line 61 in file `TermAdapter.java` ? According to the stack trace you posted it is in method `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Line 61 is holder.termItemView.setText(name); 

in this block:
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TermAdapter.TermViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(mTerms!=null){
            Terms current=mTerms.get(position);
            String name= current.getTermName();
            holder.termItemView.setText(name);

Comment: You should [edit] your question and indicate the line throwing the `NullPointerException`. Question details should be in the question and not in comments to the question. That said, the cause of the exception is apparently due to either `holder` being null or `holder.termItemView` being null. Can you debug your code to check which one is null? Alternatively, method `setText` may throw `NullPointerException` if its method argument is null. Can you check the source code of method `setText` to verify? And if so, then check whether `name` is null.